# Script to prevent screen blanking using "mouse move" doesn't work

Tags: bash-script

This is my attempt to make a script that will use a "mouse move" to prevent screen blanking while watching videos. I'm hoping to use the value for highest CPU% process in `top` and if CPU usage exceeds 5%, a mouse move should occur.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep_period=60s 

while true; do
  if (( $(top -bn 1 | sed -nrs '8p' | awk '{ print $9 }') -gt 5 )); then 
    while (( $(top -bn 1 | sed -nrs '8p' | awk '{ print $9 }') -gt 5 )); do
      xdotool mousemove 0 100
      xdotool mousemove 0 50
      sleep ${sleep_period}
    done
  else
    sleep ${sleep_period}
  fi
done
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. The errors are like this:

```
[07:20 PM] /bin $ noo.sh
/home/vasa1/bin/noo.sh: line 6: ((: 0.0 -gt 5 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 -gt 5 ")
/home/vasa1/bin/noo.sh: line 6: ((: 6.4 -gt 5 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".4 -gt 5 ")
```

How do I fix this? (Please note that I'm not experienced in scripting.)

---

Based on answers here, I put together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep_period=5m 

while true; do
  if [[ $(top -bn 1 | sed -nrs '8p' | awk '{ print int($9) }') -gt 8 ]]; then 
    while [[ $(top -bn 1 | sed -nrs '8p' | awk '{ print int($9) }') -gt 8 ]]; do
      xset -dpms; xset s off
      xset +dpms; xset s on
      sleep ${sleep_period}
    done
  else
    sleep ${sleep_period}
  fi
done
```

Then, I reported this code over at Ubuntu Forums and [Vaphell](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175197&p=12793043#post12793043) worked on it further. Below is Vaphell's version and is what I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep_period=5m 

while true; do
  if top -bn 1 | awk 'NR==8 { exit !($9>8); }'; then
    xset -dpms; xset s off
    xset +dpms; xset s on
  fi
  sleep ${sleep_period}
done
```

Comment: to start with, `-gt` expects integer operands, not floating point. and i'm not sure why you're using `((`...`))` rather than just `[`...`]`.  or why you're using CPU% as the trigger...or even why you're extracting CPU% utilisation from a curses program like top rather than something like `ps -heo %C --sort -%cpu | head -1`

Comment: IMO, you would be better off finding out why your video player program isn't disabling the screensaver and fixing that.  Which player do you use? (e.g. totem, vlc, ...)  and what desktop/window-manager (gnome, xfce, lxde, kde, other) and which screen-saver.

Comment: @CraigSanders there's a long standing bug that results in vlc not being able to communicate with `gnome-sceensaver` and maybe others. I haven't looked into it for a while but it used to drive me up the wall too. See [here](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/4739) for example.

Comment: yeah, i've run into vlc/gnome issues before.  iirc, i ended up using `xset` as suggested by Raphael below.

Comment: @CraigSanders, **1** as I admitted in the last line of the question, I'm not experienced in scripting; **2** I want something that will work with GNOME Mplayer, Vlc, Firefox and Chrome without my intervention; **3** I'm using Openbox without a DE (but the distro is Lubuntu 13.04) so I'm guessing it's xscreensaver and I don't have gnome-screensaver installed.

Comment: Perhaps more than a bit related: http://xkcd.com/196/

Comment: Aww, @ZachSmith, your comment was hidden, so I just went off and found that to post myself. I was going to just say [Really?](http://xkcd.com/196/)

Comment: May I suggest that you simply install an application to prevent screen-blanking while videos are running? I use [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine), which works very well indeed.

Comment: @PaddyLandau, nice to see you here :) I do know about the existence of a lot of ready-to-use scripts and the Caffeine ppa. As you can see from the answers and comments, I'm learning a lot more this way than by using something out of the box.

Comment: @vasa1 Indeed, doing it yourself certainly teaches you plenty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of issues, first, you will need 2 iterations of `top` each time, see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/610068/151431) and the bug report [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619).

The other problem is that bash does not do floating point, so if your CPU usage is something like `6.2`, the `.2` will break the script. Bash is simply not designed for 'complex' arithmetic operations.  One way around this would be to move the `>5` check inside your `awk` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep_period=60s 

while true; do
    until top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | sed -nrs '8p' | awk '{if($9>5){exit 1}else{exit 0}}'; do
      xdotool mousemove 0 100
      xdotool mousemove 0 50
      sleep ${sleep_period}
    done
   sleep ${sleep_period}
done
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
xset -dpms; xset s off
```

to stop the screen from going black.

To enable this again use

```
xset +dpms; xset s on
```

So `-dpms` disables the the power energy saving features, which can turn off the whole monitor and `s off` turns off the screen saver feature of the X server.

This does not work with the `xscreensaver`, which was mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Doesn't that assume you are using `xscreensaver`? Will it work with _any_ screensaver? Even DE ones like `gnome-screensaver`?

Comment: @terdon As far as I know this disables all types of screensavers.

Comment: I want something that doesn't need my intervention

Comment: @vasa1 as long as this works for your screensaver, it needs no more intervention than your script. You just run that command once and the screensaver is off.

Comment: @terdon, yes, but won't I need to turn it on again (in the same session)?

Comment: @vasa1 you could use this instead of the `xdotool mousemove 0 100`.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens, how would the code look then? Would your first line replace the first xdotool and the second line replace the second one? And would everything else be the same?

Comment: I can confirm this does not work with xscreensaver and Cinnamon 1.8.8

Comment: @terdon from the xscreensaver man page "As of version 3.28 (Feb 2001), the ~/.xscreensaver file controls the configuration of your display’s power management settings: if you have used xset(1) to change your power management settings, then xscreensaver will override those changes with the values specified in ~/.xscreensaver (or with its built-in defaults, if there is no ~/.xscreensaver file yet.)". I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: Huh, neither did I :). I just saw it didn't work but I guess using the file should provide a workaround, thanks!

Comment: @vasa1 I would replace the until loop in @terdons answer with an if else. In the if I would use the test from the loop and if it is true then `xset -dpms; xset s off` and in the else I switch it back on. Mh should I write it in a new answer?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens, as things stand, I've reverted to a version of the code I used originally but using the `int` idea provided by @drewbenn [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91270/15760) and your` off` and `on` xset codes in place of the mouse move ones. It now seems to work fine at least over a couple of hours last night in my specific situation.

Comment: @vasa1 would you like to share your solution for other people who have the same problem?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens, please see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install xdotool & rand. Example on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install xdotool rand
```

Then run this one-liner in a terminal (as user):

```
eval $(xdotool getdisplaygeometry --shell); while true; do xdotool mousemove `rand -M $WIDTH` `rand -M $HEIGHT` && sleep $((`rand -M 300` + 120)); done;
```